# Javascript - Dynamic Tooltip in TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, tooltip

I'm attempting to get the following functionality, but can't seem to find a good way to do it:

There's a textbox where the user inputs some text, for example, "**The apple is red.**"  I then want a custom tooltip to appear depending on which word the mouse is hovering over.

So if I mouseover **apple**, I want to see a tooltip saying *Apples are a fruit!*, if I hover over **red**, I want to see *Red is a color!*, but I don't want anything to happen if I over over either **The** or **is**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any code you have written already? otherwise i'd suggest a tool tip plugin.

Answer (score 0):

this is (probably) impossible with a normal textbox.

You'd have to use a "contenteditable" element (e.g. div) and wrap words in tags (e.g. span) while user is typing...

Usually tooltips need a target, which must be a html element. I haven't seen a tooltip that you could attach to a single word inside a tag.